# Is there a special trick to install fonts with innosetup?

Tags: windows, fonts, inno-setup

Using this line to install font in innosetup.

```
Source: Executables\Tools\Fonts\password.TTF; DestDir: "{fonts}"; 
  Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; FontInstall: "Password"
```

I can see the files getting copied over to the `c:\windows\fonts` folder, but they are not registered under fonts. Basically they are getting copied but not installed.

Comment: Perhaps you enter wrong font name. `FontInstall tells Setup the file is a font that needs to be installed. The value of this parameter is the name of the font as stored in the registry or WIN.INI. This must be exactly the same name as you see when you double-click the font file in Explorer. Note that Setup will automatically append " (TrueType)" to the end of the name.` Double-Click your TTF and see what it the real full name of the font.

Comment: Your code works for me (using `password.ttf` I've found at https://github.com/davidagraf/passwd/blob/master/public/ttf/password.ttf). I can see the font in *Fonts* control panel as "Password Regular"

Comment: @Roben Thank you. I've read the same article and double checked the font name. Since this code worked for Martin, i have to assume that it may have something to do with the permissions on this particular machine. I will try it on a different one.